# Access 2010 SQL - Change Parameter Name?

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is my first post. I am a newbie to Access 2010 and SQL.

I have a hotel booking database and the SQL code I am using to run my query for vacant rooms is as follows:

```
PARAMETERS [Start Date] DateTime, [End Date] DateTime;
SELECT R.*, [Start Date] AS Expr1, [End Date] AS Expr2, *
FROM ROOMS AS R LEFT JOIN (select B.RoomNo from Bookings B

where ([Start Date] between B.ArrivDate and (B.ArrivDate + BKGNS.DURSTAY))

AND ([End Date] between B.ArrivDate and (B.ArrivDate + B.DURSTAY))

)  AS BKD ON R.RoomNo = BKD.RoomNo
WHERE (((BKD.RoomNo) Is Null));
```

My question is this - where I have `BKGNS.DURSTAY`, can I rename the parameter box that comes up when the query is ran with something like "Please Enter the Duration" rather than "BKGNS.DURSTAY" which currently appears on the parameter box?

Hopefully I have explained this correctly as I am a newbie to both Access and SQL.

Comment: Have you tried renaming GKGNS.DURSTAY to [Please Enter The Duration]?  Give it a try.  (hint: the square brackets] are required)

Comment: Thank you tgolisch. That did the trick. I feel embarrassed now it was that easy to fix. I could have sworn that I tried that.Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry Guys, I am unable to mark this question as answered as it is my first post. Hopefully someone can edit this for me? Many thanks.

Comment: @tgolisch would have to move their comment to an answer for that to work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not have table GKGNS in any of your FROM clauses, it is treating GKGNS.DURSTAY as a variable.  So, you could just use a different name.  Instead of GKGNS.DURSTAY, use [Please Enter The Duration]